# Allocate exception for servlet in jBoss

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, jboss

I have index.jsp

```
<form method="POST" action="addEntry">

</form>
```

Submits to `addEntry.java`  (servlet)

Mapping in `web.xml`

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>addEntry</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.addEntry</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addEntry</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addEntry/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Using jBoss 7
When i submit the form, I get

servlet com.test.addEntry is unavailable.

Allocate exception for servlet.

I have added the dependencies for servlet jars in pom.xml as

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Error Logs

[image]

Comment: First of all you need only one version of `servlet-api`, so remove one. Second, the error is a `ClassNotFoundException`. Be sure that qualified name of the class is `com.test.addEntry`. Try add `@WebServlet` in your servlet and remove mapping from `web.xml`.

Comment: Result is the same. ClassNotFound for servlet after following above steps.

Comment: Can you update question with your `addEntry` servlet? And if you are using any IDE, try clean, rebuild and refresh `JBoss` too